# What is the preferred syntax for initializing an object to pass as an argument in C++08?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a struct that I am just using as an aggregate data holding device. As an example, a struct below holds two integer values. Let's assume I have a vector of these structs called myVec and I want to add a new struct to the vector with push_back. My understanding is that in C++11 and after one can achieve this without needing to make a named variable and passing that variable as an argument but instead can do the following.

```
struct coordinate {
    int y;
    int x;
};
//assume an initialized vector<coordinate> myVec 
//and two ints newY, newX not known at compile time
myVec.push_back( {newY,newX});
```

Based on the Notes section of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization, 
It seems like this is an example of using aggregate initialization in a constructor initializer list but I might be wrong about that. That source indicates that this syntax doesn't work pre-C++11 and while it works with MSVS2017 it doesn't with Visiual C++ for Python which is what I am targeting. Is there a syntax pre-C++11 that would allow me to add another struct to the vector without first making a named struct variable and passing that named variable to the push_back function? While this is a single example of what I'm trying to accomplish, I will have several such vectors in my project and the structs won't always be simple pairs of ints. I would prefer to avoid having several "temp" dummy variables floating around as placeholders for arguments simply because it feels cleaner to avoid having them floating around. An example of what I would prefer to avoid but will use if necessary is given below. The example adds the list of all coordinates where both the x and y values are between 0 and 9 inclusive to the vector.

```
coordinate temp = {0,0};
for (int r = 0; r < 10; ++r){
    for (int c = 0; c < 10; ++c){
        temp.y = r;
        temp.x = c;
        myVec.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: C++08? Do you mean C++03 or C++98?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the nomenclature to be perfectly honest. My searching seems to indicate the compiler I use is essentially the same as MSVS08 (which I am using because this is ultimately part of a Windows based cython package and this was the only compiler that would work that I could find.) I essentially just mean compatible with the most recent version of C++ as of 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give your struct a constructor:

```
  struct coordinate {
        int x, y;
        coordinate( int ax, int ay ) : x(ax), y(ay) {}
  };
```

You can then say things like:

```
 myVec.push_back( coordinate( 12, 42 ) );
```

Comment: Set the parameter defaults to Zero : `coordinate( int ax=0, int ay=0 ) : x(ax), y(ay) {}`

Comment: @James Why do you think that is desirable? Why do so many people seem to think that zero is a magic "ok" value? There is nothing in the OP's question that indicates that he wants this, and default constructors a source of many hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: Because of the Vector.

Comment: @James vectors do not require the things they contain to be default constructible.

Comment: `std::vector<coordinate> myVec;
myVec.resize(10);`

Comment: @James `std::vector<coordinate> myVec; myVec.resize(10, coordinate(0,0));`

Comment: This is precisely the sort of thing I was looking for although, many thanks.